# Random sampling of two vectors, finding mean of sample, then making a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, sampling

Thanks for your time!

My data frame is simple. Two columns: the first has genotype (1-39) and second has trait values (numerical, continuous). I would like to choose 8 genotypes and calculate the mean and stdev of the associated trait values.

In the end I would like to sample 8 genotypes 10,000 times and for each sample I would like to have the stdev and mean of the associated trait values. Ideally this would be in a matrix where each row represented a sample, 8 columns for each genotype, and 2 final columns for stdev and mean of the trait values associated with those genotypes. This could be oriented the other way too.

1. How do you sample from two different columns in a data frame so that both values show up in your new sample? i.e genotypes and trait values with mean and stdev calculated
2. How do you get this sample into a matrix as I've described above?
3. How do you repeat the process 10,000 times?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

This would return a single sample of all rows with genotype in a random sample of 8 traits:

```
dat[ dat$genotype %in% sample(1:39, 8), ]
```

The `replicate` function is designed to repeat random process. Repeat 3 times getting the sd of "trait" from such a sample of 2 genotypes:

```
dat <- data.frame(genotype=sample(1:5, 25,replace=TRUE), trait=rnorm(25) )
replicate ( 3, sd(dat[ dat$genotype %in% sample(1:5, 2), "trait" ]) )
[1] 0.7231686 0.9225318 0.9225318
```

This records the sample ids with the means and sd values:

```
replicate ( 3, {c( samps =sample(1:5, 2), 
                   sds=sd(dat[ dat$genotype %in% samps, "trait" ]) ,
                   means = mean(dat[ dat$genotype %in% samps, "trait" ]) )} )
            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
samps1 1.0000000 1.0000000 5.0000000
samps2 5.0000000 3.0000000 1.0000000
sds    0.8673977 0.8673977 0.8673977
means  0.2835325 0.2835325 0.2835325
```